# Unable to Auto Post In Buddy Press Activity from Elementor-Pro Form

Tags: theme-customizer, buddypress

I seek help with Wordpress usecase that I am unable to accomplish.
I have created a Elementor Form in Pop up with a field File Upload. When I click on upload button, I want to show the uploaded image in the activity section of the Olympus activity page with some text such as "Your photo is ready to share with the community!!! You look beautiful"
Elementor Form:
[image]

Buddy Press Activity Page:
[image]

Comment: I don't know BuddyPress (or Olympus? Is that the theme?) - is this a post on your BuddyPress wall, or a notification at the top of the page, or something else?

Comment: Olympus is the theme [https://olympus.crumina.net/] BuddyPress is the plugin. My activity screenshot is the post section on the wall.